# pymilvus.exceptions.ParamError: <ParamError: (code=1, message=('Field data size misaligned

Tags: exception, milvus, importdata

I want to  inport some data into milvus database。

sample data:

```
{'CN': '计费办法名称', 'EN': 'Fee Method Name', 'ID': '0867', 'DESC': '计费办法的名称。'}
```

but I got this error:

```
Failed to insert batch starting at entity: 0/808
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/itzuser/pythonProject/load_to_milvus.py", line 97, in \<module\>
MilvusWrapper.from_texts(texts,embed_model=embed_model,
File "/home/itzuser/pythonProject/milvus_wrapper.py", line 811, in from_texts
vector_db.add_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas)
File "/home/itzuser/pythonProject/milvus_wrapper.py", line 456, in add_texts
raise e
File "/home/itzuser/pythonProject/milvus_wrapper.py", line 450, in add_texts
res = self.col.insert(insert_list, timeout=timeout, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/collection.py", line 497,   in insert
res = conn.batch_insert(
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 127, in  handler
raise e from e
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 123, in handler
return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 162, in handler
return func(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 102, in handler
raise e from e
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 68, in handler
return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 572, in batch_insert
```

raise err from err
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 552, in batch_insert
request = self._prepare_batch_insert_request(
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 536, in _prepare_batch_insert_request
else Prepare.batch_insert_param(collection_name, entities, partition_name, fields_info)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/prepare.py", line 520, in batch_insert_param
return cls._parse_batch_request(request, entities, fields_info, location)
File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/prepare.py", line 488, in _parse_batch_request

```
raise ParamError(
pymilvus.exceptions.ParamError: \<ParamError: (code=1, message=('Field data size misaligned for field \[ID\] ', 'got size=\[807\] ', 'alignment size=\[808\]'))\>
```

What is this reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is particularly unhelpful, but this error relates to the fact that the **different rows of your insert have different fields in them**.

As an example of how this might happen, you might have used a splitter on a corpus of data and that splitter adds metadata to the resultant splits, and then you're aiming to put the splits, their metadata, and their embedded vectors into the database, *but this splitter doesn't always add all the same metadata fields to every single split*.

`pymilvus` takes the first row of data, uses that as the canonical length (808 in your case) and then validates that every other row is that length. It comes across a row of length 807 in your case, and that makes it error.

Why does `pymilvus` do this? Ultimately, it comes down to this: Milvus [doesn't support nullable fields at the moment](https://github.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/issues/1705). Every field must be present in every row of the data you're adding.